# Error when checking input: expected conv1d_195_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1229, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My current problem lies in the reshaping of my array for which I keep getting the error

> Error when checking input: expected conv1d_267_input to have shape (1229, 1) but got array with shape (1, 1)

My code is the one below for which I created the following mini example:

```
Xtrain = np.expand_dims(np.random.normal(size=(1229, 1)),axis=-1)
Ytrain = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(1229,))

lr = 0.0001
def model():  
    n_timesteps =X_train.shape[0]
    n_features = X_train.shape[1]
    n_outputs =  1
    
    inputA = keras.layers.Input(shape=X_train.shape[1:])
    
    x = keras.models.Sequential()
    x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
    x.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(3))
    x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
    x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
    x.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    x.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation = 'relu'))
    
    x.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=Adam(lr=lr),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(x.summary())
    return x

model = model()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit: The input shape of my sequence/array is (100000,1).

Comment: What are the shapes of the objects you are passing to the network? E.g. Images for a classifier network could be of shape (28,28,1).

Comment: no. in my case I'm working with sequential data which are of shape (10000,1).

Answer (score 0):

Input shape must be equal to the shape of each inidivial input, For example, `X_train[0] = [-0.42076894]`, then `X_train[0].shape = (1, 1)`. The input shape must be same as the X_train[0].shape.

Please find the working code below:

```
X_train = np.expand_dims(np.random.normal(size=(1229, 1)),axis=-1)
Y_train = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(1229,))

lr = 0.0001
def model():  
    n_outputs =  1    
    
        x = keras.models.Sequential()
        x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu',padding='same', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
        x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu',padding='same',))
        x.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(1))
        x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu',padding='same',))
        x.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu',padding='same',))
        x.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
        x.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_outputs, activation = 'relu'))
    
    x.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(x.summary())
    return x

model = model()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Output is as follows:

```
Model: "sequential_21"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_67 (Conv1D)          (None, 1, 64)             256       
                                                                 
 conv1d_68 (Conv1D)          (None, 1, 64)             12352     
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_15 (MaxPoolin  (None, 1, 64)            0         
 g1D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv1d_69 (Conv1D)          (None, 1, 128)            24704     
                                                                 
 conv1d_70 (Conv1D)          (None, 1, 128)            49280     
                                                                 
 flatten_15 (Flatten)        (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_14 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 129       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 86,721
Trainable params: 86,721
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
39/39 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 1.9266 - accuracy: 0.5159
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fa601a1c710>
```

Please let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!